# java NullPointer Exception

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Currently developing a mobile app using java with android studio. (Beginner) I have 3 fragments (ToDo,Doing,Done) with on top a tablayout(ToDo,Ongoing,Finished) and a toolbar with an add button.

The add button should create a list allowing the user to modify the content of each `list(Recyclerviewer)`

Obtain error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference`

Below is a screenshot

[image: kanban]

Code

```
public class kanbanManagement extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager2 viewPager2;
    private MyFragment adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView2;
    private com.example.myhouse.recyclerKanbanAdapter recyclerKanbanAdapter;
    ArrayList<kanbanItems>listKanban;
    Button btn_Add;
    public kanbanManagement() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kanban_management, container, false);
        tabLayout=view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager2=view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager2);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("To Do"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("On going"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Finished"));
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getParentFragmentManager();
        adapter = new MyFragment(fragmentManager , getLifecycle());
        viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(position));
            }
        });
        recyclerView2=view.findViewById(R.id.taskList);
        listKanban= new ArrayList<>();
        btn_Add=view.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        recyclerKanbanAdapter= new recyclerKanbanAdapter(getActivity(),listKanban);
        btn_Add.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            recyclerView2.setAdapter(recyclerKanbanAdapter);

        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: `recyclerView2` is null, indicating that `findViewById` did not find a result.

Comment: yes found that when debugging. Any solution?

Comment: Well you'll need to investigate why it cannot find a result. Run a debugger to determine the actual value of `R.id.taskList` when running your code, and see what the ID _should_ be. It more than likely is a mismatch.

Comment: its 2 different xml layouts. am I correctly doing the findviewbyid

Comment: Can you provide the `layout.xml` of your views? I am also curious why you set the adapter on a button click. It could be set while creating the view, because its initial data is a empty list.

Comment: @yanishappadoo add `LayoutManager` to manage your `recyclerViews`. How your recyclerView shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't fully understand your code. So, without checking your complete code. My guess is that you haven't used `LayoutManager` to show your `listKanban`. So add `layoutManager` code and run again.

Add the below code inside your `onCreateView`.

```
LinearLayoutManager myLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(myLayoutManager); // your recyclerView where you want to show your `ArrayList`.
```

Let me know if the problem is not solved yet.